# How to use indexOf? Please help a beginner out

Tags: java, methods, char, java.util.scanner

So I want to know what `indexOf()` does. As I want to use it in my program it find out how many vowels are in a word that the user inputs.

```
public static boolean methodCheck(char a){
       return "AEIOUaeiou".indexOf(a) != -1;
}
```

But that doesnt seem to work at all hahah. as I have no idea what `indexOf()` actually does. anyway here is my program so far(sorry if its bad I'm really new). I left 5 questions too that would help me a lot! please and thank you for your help :D

```
import java.util.Scanner;



public class vowelCounter {


private static String input = methodInput(); //1. is there any other way to make a global Scanner?


public static void main(String[] args){



    System.out.println("Enter word");
    System.out.println(input);
    System.out.println("This word has" + methodCheck('a')); //2. what should i put in my parameters? 


}

public static boolean methodCheck(char a){

return "AEIOUaeiou".indexOf(a) != -1; //3. what does this line do?


}

public static String methodInput(){


    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    String input = keyboard.nextLine();

    return input;

        //4. the output is 'hastrue' why is that?
        //5. how can i make this program better?

}

}
```

Comment: `Returns the index within this string of the first occurrence of the specified character.` http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf(int)

Comment: this is basic stuff; please do some research before posting questions here.... a mere google search on **indexOf** will fetch you desired results..

Comment: First, you should use meaningful names. As an example, `methodCheck` appears like you wanted `isVowel`. Next, you might consider a `countVowels` method to use `isVowel`.

Comment: @MiteshPathak what's basic to you may not be basic to someone else. One could argue any question regarding anything about syntax would be "basic" stuff since it's all (ideally) documented anyways.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't know what a method does, then the solution is to go look at what it does. For example, the [java documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf%28int%29) will tell you that

> public int indexOf(int ch)
>
> Returns the index within this string of the first occurrence of the specified character
>
> In either case, if no such character occurs in this string, then -1 is returned.

How you're using it is not necessarily wrong, considering how the method returns -1 if the character wasn't found. But if you want to check how many vowels there are in a word that the user enters, it wouldn't be right to check whether the word they entered is in the string of vowels.

Answer (score 0):

All the standard Java libraries, classes and methods have Javadoc that describes what they do.

All you need to do is look up the Javadoc and they describe it.

In this case the Javadoc is at: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf(int)

Your first step with any question like this should always be the documentation, then if that doesn't work try doing a web search looking for examples. For example 5 seconds on google putting in "java indexOf example" found me:
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_indexof.htm

Then if that doesn't work you can try asking the question here.

Answer (score 0):

When you have the word `boolean` before the name of a method, that means that the method will return either the value `true` or the value `false`.  And it's this `true` or `false` value that your program is printing out, on the same line as "This word has".

This particular method will return `true` if the character you pass to it is a vowel, or `false` otherwise.  The method `indexOf` tells you which character of a `String` is the first one that is equal to the value that you pass in to the method.  It returns `0` for the first character, `1` for the second character and so on.  It returns `-1` if none of the characters match.  In this case, you're just checking whether the value returned by `indexOf` is or isn't `-1` - in other words, whether the character is or isn't in the `String "AEIOUaeiou"`.

Answer (score 0):

`indexOf(String str)` Returns the index within this string of the first occurrence of the specified substring. If no such value of `str` exists, then -1 is returned.

For examples :

> int num1 = "AEIOUaeiou".indexOf("a"); // it gives 5
>
> int num2  = "AEIOUaeiou".indexOf("A"); // It gives 0
>
> int num3 = "AEIOUaeiou".indexOf("z"); // It gives -1

Answer (score 0):

**1** *Don't do that!* Create a scanner in main, read input with it and then call your method(s).

**2** How about `countVowels(input)`? You'd need to write an `static int countVowels(String input)` method.

**3** Returns true since you pass in `'a'`.

**4** See number **3**.

**5** See number **2**, and add a `static boolean isVowel(char a)`.

Comment: Wow, looking back on my old code.. Kinda cool to see how far ive come :')

Answer (score 0):

Here is what the indexOf method does

```
string.indexOf(searchvalue,start)
```

**Parameters**

```
searchvalue : Required. The string to search for 
start       : Optional. Default 0. At which position to start the search
```

**Return Value**

```
Number : The position where the specified searchvalue occurs for the first time, or -1 if it never occurs
```

In simple terms, the index of method checks the first occurence of the value passed to it from the start position(if specified) and returns the position at which the value was first encountered in the string.

eg.

```
String s = "AEIOUaeiou";
s.indexOf("a");     //This would get a value of 5.
s.indexOf("v");     //This would get a value of -1, since it doesn't have the character v
```

To answer your questions,

1. You can directly declare the scanner as private and use it in the
   entire program

   ```
   `private static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);`
   ```
2. you can write a method that receives the String input by the user
   and then checks if the String contains any of the vowels. You can
   use indexOf or contains methods to check for the each vowel using
   the indexOf method.
3. Already described above.
4. A better way to do it would be as follows.

public class vowelCounter{

```
    public static void main (String[] args) {
      Scanner keyboard = new Scanner (System.in); // No need to declare it as global. You use it only once.
      System.out.println ("Enter word : ");   //Prompt the user to enter a word    
      String input = keyboard.nextLine ();  //Fetch the word that the user enters into a String 
      System.out.println ("This word has" + countVowel (input)); // Pass the string to the method to check if it has vowels.
    }

   private static int countVowel (String a) {
     int count = 0;
     String s =  a.toLowerCase ();    // convert the string to lower case so that you only have to check for the lower case characters
    // Here you would need to check the number of times each vowel exists in the String and incremenet the count everytime.
    return count;
   }  
}
```